How to display img like backgroundimage using object-position with overflow: clip. I guess there is noway. maybe already asked but search power is low
How to display img like backgroundimage using object-position with overflow: clip. I guess there is noway. (maybe already asked but my search power is low.)
Should I use backgroundimage or maybe...?


.img-container:first-child img {
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: top 100px;
}

.img-container a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: clip;
}
<ul class="blue-edge-parent">
  <li class="img-container">
    <a href="privacy"><img src="privacy" alt="privacy">
      <p>privacy</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="img-container">
    <a href="privacy"><img src="privacy" alt="privacy">
      <p>privacy</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="img-container measure-trans-parent">
    <a href="privacy"><img src="privacy" alt="privacy">
      <p>privacy</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>



I guessed there need object-fit but it doesn't work.
And I thought there must be content is smaller than parent.
I'm sorry. I want to use tab key but I couldn't.
P.S
enter image description here

“but it doesn’t work” isn’t very helpful. Please describe exactly what you want to achieve and what isn’t working in your current code.

P.S. It doesn't appeared any change than before when added the property object-position and then object-fit. I want to sift the img with using overflow: clip;. Any other good way or I should use backgroundimage? Hmm, is this much to describe?

It is really hard to understand, what you are trying to ask here. Please provide an example of what exact background-image effect you want to replicate. Use placeholder images from a service like https://placehold.co

I'm sorry. I'm not native in English. On using native language, coworker barely understand my saying though. ...OK. I'll make example. Please wait a minutes. Thanks.

Sorry, but I still can not tell what you actually want.

np. But Thanks!

It looks as though you need some sort of object- (or background-) position and size. Do you want to have the same percentage of the image shown on any size device/container?

Yes. But...well... I inspired and remembered suddenly. If I used position relative and absolute, can we solve it? Maybe not?

Is there a reason for not using background rather than an actual element?

Because there is no alt tag. I'm coding the HP that maybe blind people use.
But at last, I should use the background...

Understood, you need it for accessibility, thanks for the clarification.

OK...It looks end up to use backgroundImge...more than any other. Please tell me if we can use any other good way. I'll return lately.

Finally it moved. I'm sorry for my noob action. It didn't work because I didn't set both top and left. Thanks for everyone that take parted. :D

Well... It became to not work again. Not working means that I changed property value then there is no response. And I can't figure out the reason...

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

OK my final answer that taught is clip the image (by any tool and EACH IMAGE!)
to make offset and scale the image. Try this.
